# Does not enter if statement

Tags: java

I have written my code (Java) for an assignment and this method below is part of it:`

```
public boolean checkList(String word) {
    ListNode current = firstNode;
    boolean flag = false;
    while ( current != null ) {
        System.out.println("inside while");
        if (current.getObject().equals(word)) {
            System.out.println("true");
            flag = true;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
        System.out.println("next node");
    }
    return flag;
}
```

The method is supposed to check if the String argument exists in a List of string objects and if it does, return true. After hours of debugging (with many System.outs) I realized that for some reason I can never get inside the if statement, even though in specific situations it should. (The List is not imported from java libraries, I created a List class on my own because it was requested as so)
Do you have any idea what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: We don't have your data structure or supporting code to allow us to run your code, so I believe that at this point it will be up to you to debug some more. Print out `word`, printout current's object returned by `getObject()`, find out what your program is doing and thereby figure out why your code is misbehaving. If then you're still stuck, consider creating and posting an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is firstNode and where is it assigned?

Comment: No idea.  Believe the JVM: if it tells you it won't go inside the block, it's because the condition is not satisfied.  It's easy to assume that you've done every thing correctly, and there's "no way" that the JVM should do that.  Check that assumption: the JVM is right and you are wrong.  Print out current, the result of getObject, and word to see why it's not going into that block.  Or, better yet, step through the code with your IDE.

Comment: Can you try this (for more debugging) ?   System.out.println("inside while " + current.getObject().getClass());

Comment: Note that .equals is case sensitive. You might try .equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: Hint:  `System.out.println("getObject ==>>" + current.getObject() + "<<, word ==>>" + word + "<<");`.  Then make sure there are no unexpected blanks on either side of either value.

Comment: You were right, I did the prints you told me and there was a small detail I was missing! I figured it out! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is `ListNode`, can you point out the full path of this class?

Comment: Don't use mountains of `System.out.println` statements to debug.  Learn to use a debugger.  It will save you _hours_.  And if you become a professional programmer, then knowing how to use a debugger will save _years_ of your life (which you can then spend answering questions on Stack Overflow).